# I am not able to filter a field in a Dashboard that contains Reports of different Report Types in Salesforce

Tags: standard-objects, dashboard, joined-reports, report-chart

I have a Dashboard containing few Reports with different Report Types(Opportunities, Opportunity History and Ops with Order). So in Account object, there is a custom field - say custom__c. This field, I can filter in the reports with report type (Ops with Order and Opportunities) but I was not able to see custom__c in in report with report type Opportunity History. So, I created a new formula field Oppcustom__c in opportunity object and after that I am able to use this field(Oppcustom__c) to filter in report with opportunity history report type.

But in a dashboard, that contains 8 to 10 reports of(opportunity history,Ops with order and Opporutunities) report types I am not able to filter neither custom__c nor Oppcustom__c.

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, what I think is, the fields that are common to all the reports/report types can only be used to filter is dashboard.

Any suggestion is helpful. Is any way to filter the field custom__c in dashboard ?

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done a bit using Joined Report.